# I'm trying to create a bad character filter in Python 3

Tags: python

I'm trying to set up a filter that will print out an "Bad Input" message when any character other than A, C, E, T, O, or P is entered. For some reason, I can't wrap my head around what I need to do to make sure that the findLetter() function will actually happen when a GOOD input is entered. Can anyone help me out in what I'm doing wrong in the filter()?

```
reset = True;
while ( reset == True ):

#A C E T O P
    def letterA():
        print('   *   ');
        print('  * *  ');
        print(' ***** ');   
        print('*     *');
        print('       ');   
    def letterC():
        print('*****');
        print('*    ');
        print('*    ');
        print('*    ');
        print('*****'); 
        print('     '); 
    def letterE():
        print('****');
        print('*   ');
        print('*** ');
        print('*   ');
        print('****');
        print('    ');  
    def letterT():
        print('*****');
        print('  *  ');
        print('  *  ');
        print('  *  '); 
        print('     '); 
    def letterO():
        print('*****');
        print('*   *');
        print('*   *');
        print('*****'); 
        print('     '); 
    def letterP():
        print('*****');
        print('*   *');
        print('*****');
        print('*    ');
        print('*    ');
        print('     '); 
    def findLetter():
        for x in range(len(temp)):
            if ( temp[x] == 'a' or temp[x] == 'A' ):
                letterA();
            elif ( temp[x] == 'c' or temp[x] == 'C' ):
                letterC();
            elif ( temp[x] == 'e' or temp[x] == 'E' ):
                letterE();
            elif ( temp[x] == 'p' or temp[x] == 'P' ):
                letterP();
            elif ( temp[x] == 'o' or temp[x] == 'O' ):
                letterO();
            elif ( temp[x] == 't' or temp[x] == 'T' ):
                letterT();

    def filter(y):  
        for x in range( len(y) ): #bad input filter
            while ( ( y[x] != "a" ) and ( y[x] != "c" ) and ( y[x] != "e" ) and ( y[x] != "p" ) and ( y[x] != "o" ) and ( y[x] != "t" ) and ( y[x] != "A" ) and ( y[x] != "C" ) and ( y[x] != "E" ) and ( y[x] != "P" ) and ( y[x] != "O" ) and ( y[x] != "T" ) ):
                if ( ( y[x] != "a" ) and ( y[x] != "c" ) and ( y[x] != "e" ) and ( y[x] != "p" ) and ( y[x] != "o" ) and ( y[x] != "t" ) and ( y[x] != "A" ) and ( y[x] != "C" ) and ( y[x] != "E" ) and ( y[x] != "P" ) and ( y[x] != "O" ) and ( y[x] != "T" ) ):
                    y = input( 'Please enter a valid input: A, C, E, P, O, T : ' );
                    userInput = y;
                    temp = y;

    userInput = input('Please input any word using any of the following 6 letters: A, C, E, P, O, T : ');           
    temp = userInput;   
    filter(userInput);      
    findLetter();

    repeat = input('Would you like to spell more words? (y/n): ');
    while ( repeat != 'y' and repeat != 'n' ):
        repeat = input('Would you like to spell more words? (y/n): ');      
    if ( repeat == 'n' ):
        reset = False;
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch your filter function to this:

```
def filter(y):  
    valid_letters = ['A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'E', 'e', 'P', 'p', 'O', 'o', 'T', 't']
        if not any(valid in y for valid in valid_letters):
            print('Invalid input')
            y = input( 'Please enter a valid input: A, C, E, P, O, T : ' );
            userInput = y;
            temp = y;
            filter(y)
```

What I did was create a list of valid characters, named `valid_letters`, then checked if a character in `userInput` was not in the list of valid characters with this:

`if not any(valid in y for valid in valid_letters):`

Your `findLetter` function seems fine; there's nothing I would do to change that.

(also, in Python, you don't have to show the end of a line with a semicolon :-D)

Answer (score 0):

I've edited this answer to take into account looping, it's more verbose than the other answer (which is a great answer!). Description in comments hopefully:

```
#Returns true if input is ok, otherwise false
def ok_input(userInput, allowed_letters):
    good = True
    for letter in userInput:
        if letter.upper() not in allowed_letters:
            good = False
            break
    return good

#Placeholder function
def thing_to_do_with_good_input(goodInput):
    print('My favorite word is '+goodInput)

only_allowed = ['A','C','E','P','O','T']


#Loop forever asking for input
loop_counter = 0 #<-- how many times we've done the big loop
while True:
    userInput = ''
    ok_user_input = False

    #While the user hasn't given good input
    bad_counter = 0 #<-- how many incorrect inputs were given on this big loop
    while not ok_user_input:
        print('On loop #'+str(loop_counter)+' with '+str(bad_counter)+' input attempts')
        userInput = input('Please input word w/ only A, C, E, P, O, T : ')
        ok_user_input = ok_input(userInput, only_allowed) #<-- check if the input is ok

        if not ok_user_input:
            print('Your input was not good, please try again')
            bad_counter += 1 #<-- keep track of bad input attempts

    #The user finally gave us good input
    print('Now we are over here with only good input...')
    thing_to_do_with_good_input(userInput)

    #Increment the overall loop counter
    loop_counter += 1
```

By converting the letter to capital when checking if it's in the `allowed_letters`, you don't have to include upper and lower case versions.